# CTR: Why not XOR before AES

Tags: aes

I just learned AES-CTR.

I am wondering about the security of the CTR mode. It is basically an AES of the nonce with an XOR-Encryption at the end.

Are this 2 assumptions correct?

- The nonce doesn't have to be random, can also be 0 for example, but it has to be unique in combination with the key
- XOR-Encryption needs a key with good entropy

Since AES is an encryption and not a random number generator I wonder if the output is truely random and therefore suitable as a key. (Ok, I see right now that OFB for example uses this princible, too)

But I am wondering, why the XOR-encryption is not done with the nonce before applying AES. Wouldn't that make the mode more robust if AES is found not generating enough entropy. Is this mode known/used? Would it have other known weaknesses?

Comment: It is not OTP. OTP has informationally secure but AES or any block cipher under any mode of operation is not! The nonce must be used once under the same, i.e. the nonce and key pair should occur once. One can use the same key with different nonce may times. OPT needs a random key and AES needs too. the nonce is not secret. Once can use AES ( which is a pseudo random permutation). One can use AES-CTR mode for random generation, however, TRNGS should be preferable. Nonce is public, so it will not make it secure. AES-CTR has CPA security. If you need more secuiryt use AES-GCM...

Comment: @kelalaka For me XOR=OTP. I know that AES "weakens" XOR-Security. I meant the Keystrength for the XOR-Part of the CTR (Key=AES-Output)

Comment: Ok, maybe this should be moved to crypto.stackexchange.com? Sorry, didn't know that security and crypto are different Stackexchanges (was already wondering about the lack of fitting tags for the question).

Answer (score 3):

> The nonce doesn't have to be random, can also be 0 for example, but it has to be unique in combination with the key

There is no requirement for the nonce to be random or secret for CTR mode. One nonce value is as good as any other potential value. The only requirement is that a nonce is not repeated for a given key.

This is the norm for almost all common algorithms, but check an algorithm's specification to know for sure.

Outside of cryptography, the word might be used differently. WordPress calls its anti-CSRF token a "nonce", despite the fact that they're reused. (And may need to be secret. Double submit cookie tokens need to be unpredictable.)

> XOR-Encryption needs a key with good entropy

I think by "XOR-Encryption" you mean the process by which each bit of plaintext is XORed with a corresponding keystream bit. (And not a "repeating key XOR cipher", which are especially far from being secure.)

**No.** These type of ciphers need to have an unpredictable [keystream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystream), but that doesn't require much entropy in a key. An attacker can only be 50% certain about the value of each unknown keystream bit. **Even if** they learn other keystream bit values, have a large number of ciphertext bits, or (if relevant) have multiple messages encrypted with the same key.

<sub>The reason keystream bits might become known is that a person can guess portions of the plaintext, then XOR it with the ciphertext to get raw keystream bits.</sub>

Though for serious stream ciphers, like AES-CTR, learning *any number* of those keystream bits doesn't aid you in finding the remaining unknown bits. Not unless an attacker can brute force the 128-bit to 256-bit key; an impossible task for securely generated keys.

---

Do not equate stream ciphers (XOR encryption) with OTPs. The OTP algorithm is one kind of stream cipher algorithms. Stream cipher algorithms in general are not wannabe OTPs.

OTP is just the most trivial version of a stream cipher. You assert that a **key is only used once** (*barring using multiple messages to break the key*). And you assert that each keystream bit is **statistically independent** of one another and that each bit has **exactly** 1-bit entropy. (*Trivially making it so knowing one keystream bit can't help you learn the value of the rest.*)

But this comes at the cost of needing exactly as many bits entropy as the length of the message you're trying to encrypt, making OTPs very impractical.

**Other stream ciphers** are less trivial, but allow you to use smaller keys. You get 128-bit security out of something like AES-CTR, assuming your key has 128-bit entropy. As long as key secrecy is maintained and nonce reuse is avoided, the only thing you have to worry about in practice is the internal counter rolling over. (Simply putting a hard limit on the maximum message length you can encrypt.) ... And, well, software glitches.

<sub>It's usually recommended, however, for CTR mode with 128-bit blocks, that you restrict the message length to Gigabytes or Terrabytes. It's also usually recommended that you re-key after encrypting a large number of messages. All versions of AES use 128-bit blocks, even if the key size is larger.</sub>